# I want to pass a dynamically assigned id to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I have obtained a resultset from a query and have count variable which is used to assign id to an input tag. Now i want to pass this id as parameter to a javascript function and increment/decrement the text input field value which has id assigned by the count variable value.

query used to get result:

```
for (some condition){
    $cartsql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=$key";
    $cartres = mysqli_query($connection, $cartsql);
    $cartr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartres);
    ++$count;

    <div class="entry value-minus1" onclick="decrement(<?php echo $count; ?>)"></div>
    <input class="entry value1" type="text" value="<?php echo $value['quantity']; ?>" id="<?php echo $count; ?>" />
    <div class="entry value-plus1" onclick="increment(<?php echo $count; ?>)"></div>
                <!--quantity-->
                <script>
                function decrement(<?php echo $count; ?>) {
                alert("hello");
                var y = document.getElementById(<?php echo $count; ?>).value;
                y = y - 1;
                document.getElementById(<?php echo $count; ?>).value = y;
                }
                </script>
}
```

Comment: In the first div, change `<?php $count; ?>` to `<?php echo $count; ?>` (you forgot the `echo`)

Comment: i tried but no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, there's a typo in the first div. You forgot to echo the value. Change:

```
onclick="decrement(<?php $count; ?>)"
```

to

```
onclick="decrement(<?php echo $count; ?>)"
```

Then, since you're passing the id as an argument to your js functions, you shouldn't hard code the values in that function.

You also need to output the javascript *after* your loop or you will create multiple functions with the same name which, obviously, won't work.

Change it to:

```
function increment(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).value++;
}

function decrement(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).value--;
}
```

Now there's no hard coded values in your function so you can reuse it.

Comment: the function never gets called. i have deliberately put alert inside function which never pops.

Comment: @Vk - Have you tried it after changing the code as suggested in this answer? Because your original code would have thrown errors which this should solve.

Comment: @Vk - You should also check the console in your browsers dev-tools and see if you get any error messages. If you do, please share them.

Comment: Hey Magnus! I had some other issue with the code. Looking in console helped me and solved the error.  thanks for your help. 2nd clicked my mind. !st tym using js ;)

Comment: @Vk - We all need to start at some point :-) If the answer helped you, please accept it so others know the issue have been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `id` attributes - a purely integer based id is not valid anyway ( or wasn't until HTML5 ). You can use `sibling selectors` for convenience. As demonstration the javascript functions can be radically altered / simplified

```
<style>
    div.entry{ display:inline-block;width:2rem;border:1px solid black; height:2rem; line-height:2rem; text-align:center; font-size:1rem; clear:none; cursor:pointer; }
    input[type='text']{display:inline-block;height:2rem; }
</style>

<script>
    function decrement(e){
        e.target.nextElementSibling.value--;
    }
    function increment(e){
        e.target.previousElementSibling.value++;
    }
</script>



for( $i=1; $i < 10; $i++ ){

    $value=mt_rand(20,50);

    echo "
    <div>
        <div class='entry value-minus1' onclick='decrement(event)'>-</div>
        <input class='entry value1' type='text' value='$value' />
        <div class='entry value-plus1' onclick='increment(event)'>+</div>
    </div>";
}
```

Better yet would be to remove any inline function calls and use an externally registered event handler - this keeps the HTML nice and clean and separates HTML and javascript.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
        document.querySelectorAll('div.entry').forEach( div=>{
            div.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                switch( this.dataset.dir ){
                    case 'increment':
                        this.previousElementSibling.value++;
                    break;
                    case 'decrement':
                        if(this.nextElementSibling.value > 0) this.nextElementSibling.value--;
                    break;
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>

for( $i=1; $i < 10; $i++ ){

    $value=mt_rand(5,50);

    echo "
    <div>
        <div class='entry value-minus1' data-dir='decrement'>-</div>
        <input class='entry value1' type='text' value='$value' />
        <div class='entry value-plus1' data-dir='increment'>+</div>
    </div>";
}
```